# AWS S3 ACL Permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So my bucket was and is still functioning correctly, I'm able to upload images through the API with no issues. However, I was messing around with the user policy and I made a change to the Resource for my User Policy and this caused some settings to change.

```
{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
{
  "Sid": "Stmt1420751757000",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "s3:*"
  ],
  "Resource": CHANGE MADE HERE
}
]
}
```

When I try to upload an image through my AWS account (not using the API), then the ACL public access is private by default. I tried changing my Policy version back to what I had, but no change. I am pretty inexperienced with S3, so if I'm missing crucial info regarding this issue I can provide it.

Comment: It could be 1 of the below, the API might have explicit S3 IAM permission to add to the S3 bucket.  The resource should have bucket and bucket/*  so anything under the bucket you will get same permissions

Comment: Are you trying to upload through the web console? Is the API using access keys from the same user or different credentials? The change to the "Resource" field in the IAM policy can prevent your user from accessing the bucket (which is likely the case as @Vikram S has mentioned), but it cannot affect the S3 bucket policy or ACL. Any changes to these must be explicit and independent.

Comment: @VikramS I am using the credentials for the user I created through the API, I believe this is what you are referring to as IAM permission. Please correct me if I am wrong. And my resource does not include bucket/'*. It is only "Resource": ""arn:aws:s3:::bucket". To answer chamal, Yes, through the web console and the API using the access keys for the user mentioned above. If I could ask, do either of you know what I might have changed that now requires me to select the ACL to have public access by default? Thanks for your feedback. I will try adding the bucket/* and see if there's a change.

Comment: What is your actual desire? Do you want all objects in the bucket to be publicly accessible to anyone who knows the URL, or do you want the objects to be private?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes, I'd like all objects in this bucket to be publicly accessible by URL for reading. I'll try to be clear, this setting defaulted prior to whatever I changed. At this point, my only real question is what could have caused this setting to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want **all objects to be public**, then you should **use a Bucket Policy**.

This should typically be limited to only allowing people to download (Get) an object **if they know the name of the object**. You can use this **Bucket Policy** (which goes on the bucket itself):

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET-NAME/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This policy is saying: *"Allow anyone to get an object from this bucket, without knowing who they are"*

It does *not* allow listing of the bucket, upload to the bucket or deleting from the bucket. If you wish to do any of these operations, you would need to use *your own credentials* via an API call or using the AWS CLI.

For examples of **bucket policies**, see: [Bucket policy examples - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html)

Your **IAM User** should probably have a policy like this:

```json
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": "s3:*",
         "Resource": "*"
         "Resource": [
             "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET-NAME",
             "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET-NAME/*"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

This is saying: *"Allow this IAM User to do anything in Amazon S3 to this bucket and the contents of this bucket"*

That will grant *you* permission to do anything with the bucket (including uploading, downloading and deleting objects, and deleting the bucket).

For examples of **IAM Policies**, see: [User policy examples - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-policies-s3.html)